# How to create a regex, not able to get second group of match pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to create regex for below data to parse, but not able to get second matched pattern `2.2.2.2 testIp2`. As don't have much exposure on regex.

Data to be parsed:

```
show names
names 1.1.1.1 testIp1 2.2.2.2 testIp2
name 192.168.1.1 testIp3
umesh 192.168.1.2 testIp4
```

The regex I could create:

```
^(?:name|names)(?:\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\S+))
```

Here is my perl code snippet:

```
while( $data =~ /^(?:name|names)(?:\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\S+))/mg) {
    $LOGGER->debug("IPs : $1 : $2");
}
```

[image]

In the screenshot below, please check ip **2.2.2.2 testIP2** not being matched in regex101 tool:

Comment: 1.1.1.1 testIp1
2.2.2.2 testIp2
192.168.1.1 testIp3

Comment: So `name` has one IP and one name, `names` has a list of pairs?

Comment: How are you parsing this? Please [edit] your question and include the Perl code around your match.

Comment: yes, basically I want IP, name pairs in my perl script.

Comment: @simbabque, I've updated the question with perl code snippet and screenshot of regex 101, maybe that can help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there can be an arbitrary number of repetitions, it's probably better to extract the tokens and then loop over them using a very simple regex.

```
if($data =~ /^names?(?:\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\S+))/) {
    my $match = $1;
    while (s/$match/^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3})\s+/) {
      $LOGGER->debug("IPs : $1 : $2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just parse this. Inside a regex, you can have code in `(?{...})` structures. The variable `$^N` is the latest text you captured, and `$^R` is the result of the last `(?{...})`. It's a little mind bending, and maybe you don't want to wish this on anyone, but it's very powerful (and I spend a lot of the first chapter of [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org) on this):

```
$_ = <<~'HERE';
    show names
    names 1.1.1.1 testIp1 2.2.2.2 testIp2
    name 192.168.1.1 testIp3
    umesh 192.168.1.2 testIp4
    HERE

my @found;

() = / # list context to get all the matches with /g
    ^
    names?
    (
        \h+
        ([0-9.]+)(?{ $^N })
        \h+
        (\w+)(?{ push @found, [ $^R, $^N ] })
    )+
    /gxm;

use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( \@found );
```

This might make more sense if you see the `$^N` assigned to temporary variables (although you'd need to declare these outside the regex):

```
() = / # list context to get all the matches with /g
    ^
    names?
    (
        \h+
        ([0-9.]+)(?{ $ip = $^N })
        \h+
        (\w+)(?{ $name = $^N; push @found, [ $ip, $name ] })
    )+
    /gxm;
```

Here's the output. I made tuples, but you can process that in any way you like:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1.1.1.1',
            'testIp1'
          ],
          [
            '2.2.2.2',
            'testIp2'
          ],
          [
            '192.168.1.1',
            'testIp3'
          ]
        ];
```

It's a bit frustrating that this isn't easier in Perl, though. I'd much rather have something like this, where it's closer to a parser. The `%-` doesn't remember all of the labeled matches in a `(...)+`, just the latest one.

```
while(1) {
    if( /\Gshow names\R/gc ) {
        say "Found start";
        }
    elsif( /\Gname (?<ip>\S+) (?<name>\S+)\R/gc ) {
        ...
        next;
        }
    elsif( /\Gnames (?:(?<ip>\S+) (?<name>\S+)\h*)+\R/gc ) {
        ... something with %-, but that doesn't work ...
        next;
        }
    else { last }
    }
```